# i18next languages functionality is slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, i18next

I am using i18next in a Gatsby and React app to handle internationalization. The website is in french and english and works well. The only issue is that when I set the language to french and refresh, I notice a short delay where language is not yet loaded, so it gives me english version (which is the language I set for fallback), and quickly returns to french.

My i18next config file:

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import fr from "./i18n/fr.json";
import en from "./i18n/en.json";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";

const resources = {
  fr: {
    translation: fr
  },
  en: {
    translation: en
  }
};

i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    fallbackLng: "en",
    returnObjects: true,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
  });
export default i18n;
```

Do you have any idea how to remove this delay and load the page directly to the chosen language ?

Comment: If you set debug to true, how does the developer console log look like?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. Firstly, I changed **fallbackLng** like this

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const cookieLanguage = Cookies.get('i18next');

fallbackLng: cookieLanguage ? cookieLanguage : 'en'
```

then I wrote in my onClick function

```
const [langChanged, setLangChanged] = useState(null);
const language = Cookies.get('i18next');

const changeLanguageHandler = (e) => {
    const newLang = e.target.innerText.toLowerCase();   
    
    if (language !== newLang) {
        window.location.reload(true);
        broadcastChannel.postMessage("language changed");
        setLangChanged(newLang);
    }
}
```

And I used **langChanged** state like dependency in useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (langChanged) {
        i18next.changeLanguage(langChanged)
    }
}, [langChanged])
```

So it returns same delay to every language

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the fallback language is server-side rendered, and other languages are not.

If you click "view page source" in the browser you can see the original HTML code. I suppose you will see the english text, even if french is displayed on the page.

*(Note that "inspect" will display french, because this includes all dynamic changes to the DOM, while "view page source" will display the original server response.)*

So you need to render non-default languages on the server as well:

- In case you store the language in a cookie, then you can query the cookie at the server-side, and send the correct text accordingly.
- Alternatively you can use the URL to inform the server about the desired language (e.g. `/fr/mypage).

I don't use i18next, but you probably need to set the "initial store" to the desired language on the server-side, instead of set the fallback language as "initial store" and set the desired langage afterwards.

I read that you can set `initialI18nStore` and `initialLanguage` for the [`I18nextProvider`](https://react.i18next.com/legacy-v9/i18nextprovider)

See also [react.i18next Server Side Rendering](https://react.i18next.com/legacy-v9/serverside-rendering)